# took the 12.15 train OR caught the 12.15 train

Tags: meaning

Please help me to understand these complicated verbs 'to take' an 'to catch'.

I know the difference from the related topics, google e.g.
"If you want to go over to Sixth Ave., you'd better take the crosstown bus. You can catch it at Broadway...."

BUT I can't see the difference between

'they caught the 12.15 train from Oxford'

'they took the 12.15 train from Oxford'

which one is more idiomatic in terms of BrE or AmE?

p.s. please do not write that it is duplicate because it's impossible to find answer to my question. They are very useful, I've read them for many times, but I can't see clearly the difference in my examples above.

Comment: They caught/took are equally used in AmE. We *tend* to catch a train, take a bus, catch/board a plane... does that help?

Comment: Thanks. But what about BrE? Arey the equally used in BrE as well?

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question explains the difference between the two verbs. There is nothing more to it.

Comment: linked question explaination has: In British English, at least, I disagree. "How shall we get to London next week?" "I've looked at the timetable, and I think we should catch the 10:49". What the difference you see? We can't use 'take' here, only 'catch'?

Comment: Cant help with BrE, I'm afraid.

Comment: If you do not want us to mark as duplicate you need to link to the ones you looked at and tell us the difference from your question